# How to change date format in timestamp

Tags: java, timestamp, prepared-statement

I'm using preparedStatement to update my sql table. Currently my date format is yyyy-mm-dd how to make it dd-mm-yyyy.

```
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306?user=root&password=1234&useSSL=false");
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        pstmt = con.prepareStatement(qry);
        sp = con.setSavepoint();
        System.out.println("Enter your name");
        String name = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Enter your contact number");
        long phoneNum = sc.nextLong();
        System.out.println("Purpose of visit");
        String purpose = sc.next();

        pstmt.setString(1, name);
        pstmt.setLong(2, phoneNum);
        pstmt.setString(3, purpose);

         java.sql.Timestamp  dd = new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());
        pstmt.setTimestamp(4, dd);
        pstmt.setTimestamp(5, dd);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
        con.commit();
```

Comment: Don't. Date formats are a *display* concern and not a data storage concern. Format your date immediately prior to displaying it to the user instead.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Timestamp` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use either `OffsetDateTime`, `Instant` or `LocalDateTime`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Use for example `pstmt.setObject(4, yourOffsetDateTime);`.

Comment: A timestamp is “identifying when a certain event occurred, usually giving date and time of day, sometimes accurate to a small fraction of a second” ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp)). Would dd-mm-yyyy be enough for your timestamps, not including time of day? And what is the datatype of your database columns?

Comment: @OleV.V. datatype is TIMESTAMP

Comment: @OleV.V. now im using localDate which datatype should i use in my database and in my setxx() method.

Comment: For a `LocalDate` (as in Basil Bourque’s answer, for example), the `date` datatype of MySQL matches. You still use the same `setObject` method I mentioned earlier: `pstmt.setObject(4, yourLocalDate);.`.

Comment: Now im getting this error com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect date value: '28-06-2019' for column 'login' at row 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terrible  `java.sql.Timestamp` class is now legacy, no longer needed as of JDBC 4.2 and later. For database work, use `OffsetDateTime` instead, possibly adjusting to/from `Instant` or `ZonedDateTime`.

## `LocalDate`

You seem to want only the date, without a time-of-day and without a time zone or offset-from-UTC.

To represent the date-only, use `LocalDate` class.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2019-01-23" ) ;  // By default, parses strings in standard ISO 8601 format: YYYY-MM-DD.
```

To capture the current date, specific a time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

To generate text representing that value, use `DateTimeFormatter`.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uuuu" ) ;
String output = ld.format( f ) ;
```

## JDBC

To write a `LocalDate` object to the database in a column of a data type akin to the standard-SQL type `DATE`:

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ld ) ;
```

Retrieve from database:

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

Comment: So which datetype should i use in my database and in my setxxx() method.

Comment: @Ranjan See the “JDBC” section I added.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write below code to change the format as required.

```
java.sql.Timestamp dd = new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());
String date = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(dd);
System.out.println(date);
```

> Output : 27-06-2019

Comment: Those terrible date-time classes were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310. –

Comment: @BasilBourque Thanks for pointing that out. so please can you provide me the reference of updated and latest Java time and calender classes.

Comment: See the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package of classes, the [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html), and [search Stack Overflow for `java.time`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java.time&t=osx&ia=web).